# PHP Regex not matching whole possible word

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating script thats cuts unwanted parts of string but leaving the rest of it. I have strange problem - regex I created match the string but not for all posible signs.

Tested string:

```
 $itemFullName = "10-16X4 POLI MG SELF START BLK PLASTIC";
```

"Pattern" I have:

```
POLI MG FT SDS BLK ZC
```

PHP Code:

```
if(preg_match("@(POLI){1}(.)+(BLK)@", $itemFullName))
{
    $itemAttributes = preg_replace("@(POLI){1}(.)+(BLK)@", "#", $itemFullName);
}
```

And finaly $itemAttributes is set to:

```
 "10-16X4 #K PLASTIC".
```

Look like regex catching only [POLI MG SELF START BL]K part and changing it to "#" instead of whole match **POLI MG SELF START BLK** and replace it.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `$itemFullName = "10-16X4 POLI MG SELF START BLK PLASTIC";
$itemAttributes = preg_replace("@(POLI){1}(.)+(BLK)@", "#", $itemFullName);
echo $itemAttributes;` This works for me returning `10-16X4 # PLASTIC` as expected.

Comment: [Works for me](http://3v4l.org/s7ODI) (although it is horribly inefficient)

Comment: you can also simply use `@(POLI)(.*?)(BLK)@`

Comment: You could also remove the capture groups, they aren't doing anything useful here. In fact it's possible that `strpos()`/`substr()` would be more efficient here, although the code probably reads nicer with a regex.

Comment: @DaveRandom  No i can't because in the middle of string there are something that I dont know (I have only first and last word).

Comment: @PAM That still doesn't require capture groups. [Honest](http://3v4l.org/5c74L).

Comment: @PAM Also demo of substr/strpos approach: http://3v4l.org/CuP9k

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run `preg_match` before `preg_replace`. If pattern doesn't match you will get back original string returned from `preg_replace`. Also your regex needs to be simplified too, try this code:

```
$itemAttributes = preg_replace('@\bPOLI\b.*?\bBLK\b@', '#', $itemFullName);
```

I have wrapped starting and ending string in `\b` (word boundaries) in order to avoid matching unexpected matches like `POLICY`